# How to list history commands on VMS ?

Tags: history, vms, openvms

How to list history commands on VMS ?

On linx, we can use "history".

I cannot find corresponding commands on VMS .

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The command you're looking for is `RECALL /ALL`. See this [handy-dandy list](http://www.physnet.uni-hamburg.de/physnet/vms-unix-commands.html) of OpenVMS commands and their UNIX equivalents.

Comment: if you want to see the recall buffer of another process, `$ ana/sys set proc/id=xx` and now `exam ctl$ag_clidata;400` for older versions of OpenVMS, for recent versions, just `$ ana/sys`  and then `clue process/recall`

Answer (score 3):

you can use Recall/all 
its give you last buffer commands in following format

- 42 help
- 43 @mydcl
- 44 set verify
- 45 @mydcl
- 46 create mydcl.com

now you can run again using

```
recall 42
ie 
help
```

and as in unix "!pattern" its run very last command  matching with pattern
same in OpenVMS RECALL PATTERN
example

```
$ recall s
```

the result is

```
$ set verify = procedure
```